# Linkedin Profile Picture Url Extension + Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linkedin-api, carrierwave

I've been searching for a way to construct an image from my LinkedIn profile picture and use the url with Carrierwave but it bugs out because of the missing extension in the LI url that gets retrieved.

Example of LI url: "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/......." with no .jpeg .jpg .png

When I try to do `user.remote_image_url = linkedin_url` and proceed to do `user.save` it complains about the file type not being allowed which in this case would be `''`

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve this or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a way to get the extension from LI I went away and hacked something out which seems to work fine now

```
image = open(user.linkedin_url) { |f| f.read }
File.rename(image.path, "#{image.path}.jpg")
user.image = File.open("#{image.path}.jpg")
user.save!
```